# Using std::min_element with result of a function. Nested boost::bind

Tags: c++, function, boost, bind

I have a struct called WorldPoint and a function called diagonalDistance. I want to find the closest points in a vector to the origin.

The code is pretty self-explanatory:

```
    WorldPoint closestToOrigin(std::vector<WorldPoint> vertices)
    {
            WorldPoint point(0, 0);
            boost::function<double(WorldPoint)> distToOrigin = boost::bind(&diagonalDistance<WorldPoint>, origin, _1);
            boost::function<bool(WorldPoint, WorldPoint)> compare = boost::bind(&std::min<double>, distToOrigin(_1), distToOrigin(_2)); // <- Won't compile
            startPoint = *std::min_element(vertices.begin(), vertices.end(), compare);
    }
```

Is there a way to process the arguments to a boost::function using another boost::function?

What would be the easiest way to achieve what I'm trying to do? Should I just define a local struct that has a comparison function inside of it?

Comment: inline the calls to boost::bind

Comment: inlining the binding of &diagonalDistance will make it work because bind detects inner binds and treats them specially. However, the codes' going to be a mess. Perhaps it's time to break it out into either a structure or a lambda?

Comment: Ok, I will consider structure (can't use lambda, not c++11). How do I inline the binding?

Comment: `boost::bind(&std::min<double>, boost::bind(&diagonalDistance<WorldPoint>, origin, _1), boost::bind(&diagonalDistance<WorldPoint>, origin, _2))`

Comment: strongly suggest you write a custom comparison functor... you (or your colleagues) will sorely regret such a convoluted bind expression in the future. Just saying...

Comment: I agree. Thanks everybody.

Comment: it's not only a matter of syntax complexity, but also portability to C++11